# Punctuating a list of direct non-question quotes

Tags: punctuation, quotes

What is the correct way to punctuate a list of spoken quotes?  For example:

They had a variety of excuses for missing the meeting, such as:

“We weren’t really sure we were meeting tonight. Were we?”

“Good thing I see you all the time anyway.”

“I know you understand how demanding my job is.”

Answer (score 1):

As they are not exactly quotations, but shorthand expressions for the types of excuses on offer, I would tend not to put them in quotation marks but in italics:

**They had a variety of excuses for missing the meeting, such as: *We weren't really sure we were meeting tonight, were we?; Good thing I see you all the time anyway; I know you understand how demanding my job is.***

You may wish to add the words **along the lines of** after **such as**.